# attribute error in django social auth package

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I am trying to implement login with facebook in my django project but it gives an attribute error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rsplit' in django social auth package . any one have an idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: Please add the full error message. `rsplit` is a built in string method in python. It will not work on `None`

Comment: gives error in this 
/home/impinge/gnothub/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/utils.py in module_member
                mod, member = name.rsplit('.', 1)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?